# Ubuntu Firewall Disable Through PHP

Tags: ubuntu, php

Is there a way I can execute a command line in PHP. I want to have a hidden file on my servers so If I lose access to them I can disable the firewall through the website by loading a secure .php file through my browser. The command I use to disable the fire wall is

```
sudo ufw disable
```

I'm running Ubuntu Server with apache2. I'm not sure how to execute that through PHP.

Thank you

Comment: no good will come from this - remotely executing system scripts thru sudo is dangerous. u should find another way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is setup SSH on your server. Log into the server, and disable the server that way.